# How do I find images with a similar color using Python and PIL?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a lot of images in a folder, and I would like to find images with a similar color to a pre chosen image.

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
python find_similar.py sample.jpg
```

and have that return something like:

```
234324.jpg
55.jpg
9945.jpg
345434.jpg
104.jpg
```

Is this doable?

Answer (score 4):

I cannot give you a canned solution, but here's an angle to tackle the problem. It's not PIL-specific, and it might be entirely bogus, since I have no experience in image processing.

1. Perform [color quantization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization) on the image. That gives you a palette that encodes the color information in the image without any shape information.
2. Run a [principal components analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_components_analysis) to get the dominant components in the color cube. Strictly, you could run this without quantization first, but it might be too expensive.
3. Do a least-squares fitting on the principal components of different images.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm for finding similar images is discussed in a [Question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75891/algorithm-for-finding-similar-images), you might want to implement one of those in Python & PIL.

Also, you can straightaway use the `ImageChops` module from PIL and use the `difference` method to compare two images like this:

```
import Image
import ImageChops

im1 = Image.open("original.jpg")
im2 = Image.open("sample.jpg")

diff = ImageChops.difference(im2, im1)
```

That might help you in getting some idea about the difference in your original image and the others.

There is another [similar question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189943/how-can-i-quantify-difference-between-two-images) which discusses this.

Comment: The sample image is, say, a square, left half pink, right half black. Will this find a square image with left half black and right half pink?