# Find images with similar color palette with Python

Tags: python, image, colors

Suppose there are 10,000 JPEG, PNG images in a gallery, how to find all images with similar color palettes to a selected image sorted by descending similarity?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593925/how-do-i-find-images-with-a-similar-color-using-python-and-pil

Comment: Yeah, but there are no good answers on that question. :-)

Comment: There's a lot of similar discussion here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034900/near-duplicate-image-detection/1048723#1048723

Comment: Here is another contender https://github.com/larytet-py/image-mathching The code groups the matching colors, adds percentage of the area occupied by the color group.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Build a color histogram for each image. Then when you want to match an image to the collection, simply order the list by how close their histogram is to your selected image's histogram.

The number of buckets will depend on how accurate you want to be. The type of data combined to make a bucket will define how you prioritize your search.

For example, if you are most interested in hue, then you can define which bucket your each individual pixel of the image goes into as:

```
def bucket_from_pixel(r, g, b):
    hue = hue_from_rgb(r, g, b) # [0, 360)
    return (hue * NUM_BUCKETS) / 360
```

If you also want a general matcher, then you can pick the bucket based upon the full RGB value.

Using PIL, you can use the built-in `histogram` function. The "closeness" histograms can be calculated using any distance measure you want. For example, an L1 distance could be:

```
hist_sel = normalize(sel.histogram())
hist = normalize(o.histogram()) # These normalized histograms should be stored

dist = sum([abs(x) for x in (hist_sel - hist)])
```

an L2 would be:

```
dist = sqrt(sum([x*x for x in (hist_sel - hist)]))
```

`Normalize` just forces the sum of the histogram to equal some constant value (1.0 works fine). This is important so that large images can be correctly compared to small images. If you're going to use L1 distances, then you should use an L1 measure in `normalize`. If L2, then L2.

Comment: @Frank, thanks for your advice. Could you give me some example code in Python? PIL's build-in histogram() function returns a list, how to determine how close two images' histograms are?

Comment: @Frank, looks like it requires 10,000 distance calculations when picking images with similar histogram out of 10,000 candidates? is it possible to associate numeric values with each image and store them in database thus comparison can be simplified to some sql queries?

Comment: @jack, 10,000 calcs isn't really that expensive. The best way to speed up code like this is not to reduce the histograms into integers (which can't be done the way you think) but to simply **cache** the results. Cache the sort order (per image) in the database or cache it in memory. Make sure you also store the histogram in the database or in memory so that rebuilding those sort order caches isn't expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to run a Kmeans on each palette to group colors, order each palette by their hue, then use the cosine similarity to find the most similar image.

Here is a code that will find the most similar image of ref_image in a folder of images:

```
from PIL import Image
import os
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans
from numpy.linalg import norm
from tqdm import tqdm
from skimage.color import rgb2hsv


def extract_palette(image, num_colors):
  image_array = np.array(image)
  pixels = image_array.reshape((-1, 3))
  kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=num_colors, n_init='auto')
  kmeans.fit(pixels)
  colors = kmeans.cluster_centers_
  return colors


def order_vector_by_hue(colors):
  hsv_colors = rgb2hsv(np.array([colors]))
  ordered_indices = np.argsort(hsv_colors[:, :, 0])
  ordered_rgb_colors = colors[ordered_indices]
  return ordered_rgb_colors


def cosine_sim(u, v):
  return np.dot(u, v) / (norm(u) * norm(v))


if __name__ == "__main__":
  ref_image_path = '<your-path>'
  folder = '<your-image-folder>'

  files = os.listdir(folder)

  print('processing ref image')
  image = Image.open(image_path)
  ref_colors = extract_palette(image, num_colors=32)
  ref_colors = order_vector_by_hue(colors).reshape(-1)

  print('processing candidate images')
  selected_image_path = None
  max_similarity = -1 # value for the most dissimilar possible image
  for image_path in files:
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    colors = extract_palette(image, num_colors=32)
    colors = order_vector_by_hue(colors).reshape(-1)
    similarity = cosine_sim(ref_colors, colors)
    if similarity > max_similarity:
      max_similarity = similarity
      selected_image_path = image_path

  print(f'most similar image: {selected_image_path}')
```

Edit: There are probably ways of enhancing all of this. If I had time, I would play around with palette compression using PCA and with the Lab Color Space to order (and compress?) the vectors. This solution is good enough for me right now. It could be quite slow for 10k images (kmeans). My use case is only several hundred images.

Edit2: A fast version that replace clustering is to select randomly num_colors in our pixels. Regarding what is your use case, it can be good enough.

```
def extract_palette(image, num_colors):
  image_array = np.array(image)
  pixels = image_array.reshape((-1, 3))
  selected_colors = pixels[np.random.choice(len(pixels), num_colors, replace=False)]
  return selected_colors
```