# Perceptual Hash Algorithms in Python or PHP?

Tags: php, python, algorithm, hash, perception

I've been exposed [via StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75891/algorithm-for-finding-similar-images/774916#774916) to [pHash](http://www.phash.org/), a C++ perceptual hash library for audio, video, images, and text fingerprinting - recently with preliminary bindings for PHP, C# and Java.

I'm interested in studying these algorithms and I'm wondering if there are any **open-source pure Python or PHP implementations** of the same / similar algorithm? This would make my life a lot easier.

Comment: Are you looking for these implementations so you can study them or just use them? Or both I suppose.  I ask because the pHash site has a pretty nice description of it's various algorithms. http://www.phash.org/docs/design.html

Comment: @zdav: Maybe both. But I'm more eager to learn than to use it.

Comment: @zdav: That's interesting. But all I see is graphs, I've no idea how to compute the hamming distance of a video or an audio file or how to hashify the results so that they can be easily looked up for comparison. I like the math and advanced CS knowledge (trying to get into a CS Master degree this year though) and studying the code of a language I'm more familiar with would be easier for me to understand. In case this is not possible I may try to port the C++ though.

Comment: Hamming distance is one of the basics in cryptology and hashing, so sooner or later you may have to overcome with that. The syntax of C++ and PHP is pretty similar, so C++ programs should be fairly readable once you understood the concepts of the programming language. Christoph Zauner has published his master thesis on the phash website (http://www.phash.org/docs/pubs/thesis_zauner.pdf). It has a section on image hashing and does a lot of theoretical discussion. It looks German on the outside but the thesis itself is written in English.

Answer (score 1):

I have been searching on Google, *but not much has come up*.  Since it seems you want the code for academic purposes, I would suggest:

- Hit Wikipedia - look up each algorithm and get a feel for how it works
- Check the pHash site's mailing list - I doubt you are the first person to be curious.
- Email the authors and ask what sources they used (books, papers, etc.)
- Use bookstore, library, etc. to find your own sources

I personally find that studying code is very ineffective at teaching algorithms (at first anyway, until you have a feel for the overall process).