# Is there any tips for opencv library configuration in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, sift

I want to use OpenCV to implement SIFT.  I'm new to it and I am having some difficulty configuring it properly.

I am using OpenCV 2.3.1 and Visual Studio 2010. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010/7014918#7014918) to configure them both and it works in that demo. When I try to run this [SIFT demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6705842/1285444), error LNK2019 occurs. I think the reason is I have an incomplete library dependence.  I just added core.lib & highgui.lib in the project.  I don't know what is exactly needed for this SIFT demo.

HERE IS WHAT I WANT TO KNOW:

1. In the SIFT demo I mentioned above, what libraries are needed to handle the error LNK2019?
2. How do I select opencv library for a particular project? ANY TIPS?
3. Is there any common library dependence configuration for most using scenarios?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will definitely need opencv_features2d231.lib

How do you know, which other libraries you need?
You can

1. just add them all
2. find out in the [documentation](http://opencv.itseez.com/trunk/), which library you probably need