# SURF not bound in opencv-python?

Tags: python, opencv, surf

I'm getting this error when trying to use  cv.ExtractSURF:

> cv2.error: OpenCV was built without SURF support

I found the solution for c++ in this topic:

[OpenCV SURF function is not implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175794/opencv-surf-function-is-not-implemented)

but how can I use it in python ?

---

---Edit---

---

When I try to run the example find_obj.py which uses cv2.SURF(800) I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SURF'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some functions are moved to "nonfree" module and that module is removed from the latest OpenCV package on FC18. Until this will be resolved, I made downgrade OpenCV library on my 64bit FC18 from version 2.4.3 to version 2.3.1. With downgraded library, all my python code started to work as it worked on FC17. Here is link to my post where I have described complete "downgrade" procedure:

http://www.redips.net/linux/downgrade-opencv-fedora18/

Answer (score 1):

OK this happens because I use Fedora 18 (and I installed it with yum):
http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=287847

Comment: It's not specific to Fedora - I have same issue on Linux Mint. It's known issue that should be fixed in the upcoming updates.