# Error cv::SURF::SURF(double,int,int,bool,bool) in Implementation SURF with OpenCV and C++

Tags: c++, opencv, surf

Possible duplicate of [OpenCV SURF function is not implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175794/opencv-surf-function-is-not-implemented)

My Error code is:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::SURF::SURF(double,int,int,bool,bool)" (??0SURF@cv@@QAE@NHH_N0@Z) referenced in function _main

I don't know how to fix it.

My Code is:

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <opencv2\nonfree\features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2\legacy\legacy.hpp>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat img_1 = imread("kmu1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat img_2 = imread("all.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    if(!img_1.data || !img_2.data)
    {
        cout << "could not open or find the image" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    int minHessian = 400;
    SURF surf( minHessian );

    vector <KeyPoint> keyPoints_1, keyPoints_2;
    Mat descriptors_1, descriptors_2;

    surf(img_1, Mat(), keyPoints_1, descriptors_1, false);
    surf(img_2, Mat(), keyPoints_2, descriptors_2, false);

    BFMatcher matcher(NORM_L2, false);
    vector<DMatch> matches;
    matcher.match(descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches);

    Mat img_matches;
    drawMatches(img_1, keyPoints_1, img_2, keyPoints_2, matches, img_matches);

    imshow("Matches", img_matches);

    waitKey(0);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: you haven't linked to opencv properly

Comment: I've linked it.
I'm using OpenCV 2.4.5 and IDE Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @DominikusWilly If you had linked it *properly* you would not be getting this error. Post the libraries you are linking with.

Comment: There are two pictures:https://www.box.com/s/lvhmq5hvnu8q553doz7a , https://www.box.com/s/lcof698477wtkw93ha8o

Comment: This may answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175794/opencv-surf-function-is-not-implemented

Comment: LoL... I forgot typing opencv_nonfree245d.lib in Debug and opencv_nonfree245.lib in Release. Thanks for your helping. This problem has been solved.

Comment: @john, thanks for your references. :)

Comment: @john post your answer and let Dominikus accept it, it is interesiting to have the questions answered in SO

Comment: @AnderBiguri I know little about opencv except by googling, so I don't think I.m qualified to answer, just to provide links which hopefully are correct.

Comment: @john Still got the correct answer! ;)

Comment: I make the final answer, adding opencv_nonfree245d.lib in Debug and opencv_nonfree245.lib in Release. 
Please someone type that answer. hehehe...

Comment: Also, try with the original open-source SURF code https://github.com/herbertbay/SURF

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to add those libs if you are in Debug mode and using OpenCV 2.4.5:

```
opencv_nonfree245d.lib 
opencv_features2d245d.lib
```

In Project -> Properties -> linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies.

I had the same error doing Feature Description tutorial and it fixed it.