# Find image in another image using javacv

Tags: image, opencv, javacv, template-matching

I want to find an image in another image. I already tried a "template matching" approach, but i didn't know how make it invariant to changes in scale, rotation, perspective, etc.

I have read about feature detection and suspect that usage of sift-features might be the best approach. Beside that i need an implementation of using feature detection using javacv not opencv.

Is there any implementation using feature detection or any other proposal for my problem?

Comment: You really should use more than one sentence to describe your problem!

Comment: My problem is that i have a simple image suppose a logo and i want to find this logo in another image where this image may contain light or rotated or .. so match template is not effective so i need implementation of feature detection using sift or any proposal for finding an image in another image other than match template

Answer (score 2):

If you understand the basics of JavaCV you can look at the ObjectFinder example of JavaCV.

[ObjectFinder @ code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/javacv/ObjectFinder.java)

This example shows you, how to do the important steps to solve your problem.

*Before using the ObjectFinder you have to call the following method to load the non free modules (e.g. SURF):*

```
com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_nonfree.initModule_nonfree();
```

Comment: I tried this but i have an exception                              The function/feature is not implemented (OpenCV was built without SURF support) in unknown function                                          I googled that exception and i found this solution on this [link][1]
But what i am not understanding is that i am linking opencv as a jar file so how can i link dll windows and to where

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175794/opencv-surf-function-is-not-implemented

Comment: Have you tried this: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_nonfree.initModule_nonfree();

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness. You can use the image feature matching capabilities provided by opencv, described [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html). There is even a [full implementation](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/OpenCV2_Cookbook/src/opencv2_cookbook/chapter09/RobustMatcher.scala?repo=examples&r=97b72e108789106de3e16abd0f6baf9297e28e0c) of a well working matcher with javacv (in scala though, but it's easily portable into java).