# OpenCV 3.0.0 SURF Instantiation Error with LNK2019

Tags: opencv, surf

I am attempting to implement SURF for imkage processing, but I keep getting this linking error. Which library am I missing and how do I go about solving this issue?

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol public: static struct
>   cv::Ptr __cdecl
>   cv::xfeatures2d::SURF::create(double,int,int,bool,bool)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV SURF function is not implemented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175794/opencv-surf-function-is-not-implemented)

Answer (score 0):

SURF is a "non-free" algorithm in OpenCV and therefore it is part of the [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib) repository.

You need to build OpenCV 3.0 with those extra modules from the contrib repository and then link to the xfeatures2d library.