# BRIEF implementation with OpenCV 2.4.10

Tags: c++, opencv

Does someone know of the link to BRIEF implementation with OpenCV 2.4? Regards.

PS: I know such questions are generally not welcome on SO, as the primary focus is what work you have done. But there was a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461148/sift-implementation-with-opencv-2-2) which was quite well received.

One of the answers to that questions suggests a generic manner for SIFT, which could be extended to BRIEF. Here is my slightly modified code.

```
#include <opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp> 
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

//using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{        
  Mat image = imread("load02.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
  cv::initModule_nonfree();
  // Create smart pointer for SIFT feature detector.
  Ptr<FeatureDetector> featureDetector = FeatureDetector::create("HARRIS"); // "BRIEF was initially written. Changed after answer."
  vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;

  // Detect the keypoints
  featureDetector->detect(image, keypoints); // NOTE: featureDetector is a pointer hence the '->'.

  //Similarly, we create a smart pointer to the SIFT extractor.
  Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> featureExtractor = DescriptorExtractor::create("BRIEF");

  // Compute the 128 dimension SIFT descriptor at each keypoint.
  // Each row in "descriptors" correspond to the SIFT descriptor for each keypoint
  Mat descriptors;
  featureExtractor->compute(image, keypoints, descriptors);

  // If you would like to draw the detected keypoint just to check
  Mat outputImage;
  Scalar keypointColor = Scalar(255, 0, 0);     // Blue keypoints.
  drawKeypoints(image, keypoints, outputImage, keypointColor, DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT);

  namedWindow("Output");
  imshow("Output", outputImage);

  char c = ' ';
  while ((c = waitKey(0)) != 'q');  // Keep window there until user presses 'q' to quit.

  return 0;

}
```

The issue with this code is that it gives an error: `First-chance exception at 0x00007FFB84698B9C in Project2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00000071F4FBF8E0.`

The error results in the function execution breaking. A tag says that execution will resume at the `namedWindow("Output");` line.

Could someone please help fix this issue, or suggest a new code altogether? Thanks.

EDIT: The terminal now shows an error: `Assertion failed (!outImage.empty()) in cv::drawKeypoints, file ..\..\..\..opencv\modules\features2d\src\draw.cpp, line 115`. The next statement from where the code will resume remains the same, as `drawKepoints` is called just before it.

Comment: What line do you get the error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In OpenCV, *BRIEF* is a **DescriptorExtractor**, not a **FeatureDetector**. According to [FeatureDetector::create](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#featuredetector-create), this factory method does not support `"BRIEF"` algorithm. In other words, `FeatureDetector::create("BRIEF")` returns a null pointer and your program crashes.

The general steps in feature matching are:

1. Find some interesting (feature) points in an image: `FeatureDetector`
2. Find a way to describe those points: `DescriptorExtractor`
3. Try to match descriptors (feature vectors) in two images: `DescriptorMatcher`

*BRIEF* is an algorithm only for step 2. You can use some other methods, *HARRIS*, *ORB*, ..., in step 1 and pass the result to step 2 using *BRIEF*. Besides, *SIFT* can be used in both step 1 and 2 because the algorithm provides methods for both steps.

---

Here's a simple example to use *BRIEF* in OpenCV. First step, find points that looks interesting (key points) in an image:

```
vector<KeyPoint> DetectKeyPoints(const Mat &image) 
{
    auto featureDetector = FeatureDetector::create("HARRIS");
    vector<KeyPoint> keyPoints;
    featureDetector->detect(image, keyPoints);
    return keyPoints;
}
```

You can try any [FeatureDetector algorithm](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#featuredetector-create) instead of `"HARRIS"`. Next step, compute the descriptors from key points:

```
Mat ComputeDescriptors(const Mat &image, vector<KeyPoint> &keyPoints)
{
    auto featureExtractor = DescriptorExtractor::create("BRIEF");
    Mat descriptors;
    featureExtractor->compute(image, keyPoints, descriptors);
    return descriptors;
}
```

You can use [algorithm](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_extractors.html#descriptorextractor-create) different than `"BRIEF"`, too. And you can see that the algorithms in **DescriptorExtractor** is not the same as the algorithms in **FeatureDetector**. The last step, match two descriptors:

```
vector<DMatch> MatchTwoImage(const Mat &descriptor1, const Mat &descriptor2)
{
    auto matcher = DescriptorMatcher::create("BruteForce");
    vector<DMatch> matches;
    matcher->match(descriptor1, descriptor2, matches);
    return matches;
}
```

Similarly, you can try different [matching algorithm](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html#descriptormatcher-create) other than `"BruteForce"`. Finally back to main program, you can build the application from those functions:

```
auto img1 = cv::imread("image1.jpg");
auto img2 = cv::imread("image2.jpg");

auto keyPoints1 = DetectKeyPoints(img1);
auto keyPoints2 = DetectKeyPoints(img2);

auto descriptor1 = ComputeDescriptors(img1, keyPoints1);
auto descriptor2 = ComputeDescriptors(img2, keyPoints2);

auto matches = MatchTwoImage(descriptor1, descriptor2);
```

and use `matches` vector to complete your application. If you want to check the results, OpenCV also provides [functions](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/drawing_function_of_keypoints_and_matches.html) to draw results of step 1 & 3 in an image. For example, draw the matches in the final step:

```
Mat result;
drawMatches(img1, keyPoints1, img2, keyPoints2, matches, result);
imshow("result", result);
waitKey(0);
```

Comment: If I now wanted to check the goodness of feature matching, what should I do? Is there any way to numerically quantify false positives, key point matching accuracy and so on?

Comment: When I replace "BRIEF" by "SIFT", or any other feature descriptor extractor, I get an error regarding accessing memory location at `featureExtractor->compute(image, keyPoints, descriptors);`. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Since `"SIFT"` is in non-free module, there is a note in [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#featuredetector-create): add `#include <opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp>` and call `initModules_nonfree();` before `DetectKeyPoints`

Comment: The final result `matches` is a vector of `cv::DMatch`, which has a member variable `distance`. You can apply these `distance`s on any math formula. For example, use the average distance to obtain matching accuracy.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I actually knew the SIFT part, but I decided to write the code from scratch and forgot about it. My bad. Thanks for the second part as well.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone working with newer OpenCV versions, the `::create` methods from the previous answer seem to be removed. Changed the lines to `auto featureDetector = SIFT::create();` and `auto featureExtractor = xfeatures2d::BriefDescriptorExtractor::create();`, and it works. Note that BRIEF needs opencv[contrib], and `#include <opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp>`.