# C++ - SiftFeatureDetector is not loading

Tags: c++, opencv, sift

I am currently trying to use OpenCV's SiftFeatureDetector. However, this happens:
[Click This Link For Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTHSm.png)

I saw that I needed the nonfree files. This is where i got my files from:

**features2d.hpp:**
sourceforge.net/p/emgucv/opencv/ci/3ad471d9c187b6509ca4aab439290bc76c7a258f/tree/modules/nonfree/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp

**nonfree.hpp:**
sourceforge.net/p/emgucv/opencv/ci/3ad471d9c187b6509ca4aab439290bc76c7a258f/tree/modules/nonfree/include/opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp

These are my imports:
[Click This Link For Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyOQl.png)

Can somebody please tell me what's the problem?

Comment: @devnglee I have used the line `using namespace cv;`

Comment: @devnglee my hpp file is called features2d.hpp. Do i need to get a different hpp file for sift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting files from EmguCV site. EmguCV is a wrapper around OpenCV developed for .net framework. If you are going to use OpenCV with c++ then you should use OpenCV library and header files downloadable from: http://opencv.org.

It seems that SIFT moved out of default install of OpenCV from version `3.0`. So the answer depends on the version of OpenCV you are using.

**NOTE:** If you don't want to be bothered with building OpenCV yourself, you should consider using `2.4.13.2`, or version less than `3.0`.

Tested on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015.

---

#### OpenCV 2.4.13.2

You can download prebuilt library from this [link](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases/tag/2.4.13.2). The prebuilt library includes SIFT. (In my case, since I'm on Windows, I've used `opencv-2.4.13.2-vc14.exe`) You can use SIFT like the following code.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    const cv::Mat input = cv::imread("D:/lenna.png", 0); //Load as grayscale

    // Detect
    cv::SiftFeatureDetector detector;
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
    detector.detect(input, keypoints);

    // Add results to image and save.
    cv::Mat output;
    cv::drawKeypoints(input, keypoints, output);
    cv::imwrite("D:/lenna_sift.jpg", output);

    return 0;
}
```

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbJk7.png) / [feature detected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5mUq.jpg)

(copied this minimal example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6705842/7724939))

---

#### OpenCV 3.2

You can download prebuilt library for this version from [this link](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases/tag/3.2.0), but this version doesn't include SIFT as a default installed feature. (I've checked `opencv-3.2.0-vc14.exe`  and it doesn't have it) It seems that the OpenCV community decided to remove patented algorithms like SIFT and SURF from default install starting from version `3.0`([link](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/16/where-did-sift-and-surf-go-in-opencv-3/)). To use these, you have to download the [opencv](https://github.com/opencv/opencv) *and* [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) source code and build the library yourself. You have to configure your build settings so you can build with SIFT enabled. Then you can do SIFT like follows.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    const cv::Mat input = cv::imread("D:/lenna.png", 0); //Load as grayscale

    // Detect
    cv::Ptr<cv::Feature2D> f2d = cv::xfeatures2d::SiftFeatureDetector::create();
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
    f2d->detect(input, keypoints);

    // Add results to image and save.
    cv::Mat output;
    cv::drawKeypoints(input, keypoints, output);
    cv::imwrite("D:/lenna_sift.jpg", output);

    return 0;
}
```

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbJk7.png) / [feature detected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zKhI.jpg)

---

I expect using SIFT with other versions before `3.0` should be same as `2.4.13.2`, and version including and after `3.0` to be same as `3.2`. If it's not, please let me know so I can improve this post.

Comment: Thank you sooo much. I am using OpenCV version 2.4.13.2 and it works! Thanks, once again.

Comment: I build opencv 3.3 with opencv_contribute.

Comment: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct cv::Ptr<class cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT> __cdecl cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT::create(int,int,double,double,double)" (?create@SIFT@xfeatures2d@cv@@SA?AU?$Ptr@VSIFT@xfeatures2d@cv@@@3@HHNNN@Z) referenced in function main

Comment: But in opencv2.4.9, there is not vs14. there are only for vs10, vs11, vs12.