# Java Library for Video Comparison

Tags: java, video

Is there any Java Library available for comparison of videos?
If not, any other language library that is useful for video comparison will work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you expect by "comparison of videos" ?

Comment: Like that if I give the two file Object for videos it will say whether it is identical or not.

Comment: You mean something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894361/detecting-similarity-in-two-video-files

Comment: Hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090453/how-do-you-test-if-2-large-videos-are-identical) will also help you out :)

Comment: No, that question is about algorithm. I require some libraries that are ready to use.

Comment: [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/index) may help you. I haven't tried it, but a friend did for video manipulation.