# Check similar images

Tags: php, image

We have two images with different (or not) pictures.

**How do I check by php, are images same or not?**

Width and height of the images are 100x100. This option is always equal. We should check the draw and the colors.

Which one of the php libraries you can recommend for this job?

Comment: have a look at http://www.intelliot.com/2008/03/sorted-directory-listing-image-resizing-comparison-and-similarity-in-php/

Comment: Please be more specific. What are the tolerance for declaring two images "the same". Size of the objects (scale)? Rotation? Perspective? Brightness? Others?

Comment: it will be a not hard drawn images, like a clipart

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding cropped similar images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876142/finding-cropped-similar-images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GD library. But there is no easy way to say "is this picture the same or not?" You can compare it pixel by pixel, look at individual rgba values... but what if one is slightly darker? etc.. so you would have to come up with your own algorithms for checking stuff like that.