# Finding a image that contains a cropped image

Tags: image, image-processing, pattern-matching, crop

I have a big database of pictures (say, 1 million 512x512px images) and I want to do the following query in a fast way:

**Given a cropped image, find an image from the database that contains it.**

(The closest question that I could find in StackOverflow is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876142/finding-cropped-similar-images/1389783#1389783), which I address later in this post)

The following image illustrates what I'm trying to do.

[image: Visualisation]

I have the following restrictions:

- **(I) –** The query must be **fast**. 10⁶ is a lot, so I don't think I can compare each image in the query to each of the others individually.
- **(II) –** I need to work with **cropped** images, so solutions like simple image hashing won't do it (of course, this does not apply to crop-resistant hashes)
- **(III) –** I don't know the **proportion** between the *area* of the queried image and the image that contains it. In the example above, the refrigerant is just a small portion of the original image, but the cat takes a lot of space in the image where it is contained. Although I estimate that the proportion is always between 10%~100%, I don't know the exact amount beforehand (suppose the images in queries are always 512x512px, for example)

I've gathered some information in my research:

- Simple image hash matching isn't possible because of **(II)** (I'm working with cropped parts)
- Reddit's RepostSleuthBot (available on [GitHub](https://github.com/barrycarey/RedditRepostSleuth)) is an excellent starting point for me: It can identify if an image was already posted in an efficient way. Instead of simply matching hashes, seems like it uses the [ANNOY algorithm](https://github.com/spotify/annoy) to find similar images (so it can match images with slight modifications in text or brightness, for example). The only problem with this approach is that it isn't well adapted for cropped images. So, this addresses **(I)** but not **(II)** and **(III)**.
- In my StackOverflow searches, the closest thing I found to help in this problem is that if I knew the proportion between the cropped image and the original, I could match it using phase correlation, like [this answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1389783).
  This addresses **(II)**, which is awesome, but then I'll have problems with **(I)** because I'd have to try to match with each image of the database, and it's also inviable because of **(III)**.
  [image: phase correlation example]
- A promising feature would be cropping-resistant image hashing - the paper **Efficient Cropping-Resistant Robust Image Hashing, 10.1109/ares.2014.85** describes one, but seems like it isn't *that* performant, especially taking in consideration that I'm aiming at small crops (10%~100% of the original image) and a huge amount of images.

I got stuck after this point. Is there any other algorithm or method I should be aware of? Anything will be very appreciated.

Comment: please review [ask]. this is still asking for recommendations. sorry.

Comment: Hey @ChristophRackwitz, thanks for your comment. 

I understand that open-ended questions aren't appreciated by StackOverflow, but in my view, this is more about asking if there is a specific algorithm or technique to help in my problem. 

Something more like "Is there an algorithm to find the gcd in a fast way?" *"Yes, the Euclidean algorithm! It's O(log(N))!"* and less like "How can I be better at learning algorithms??"

Do you still think I got something wrong there? I appreciate constructive feedback and will do my best to write a better question, if necessary.

Comment: just throw AI at it to generate feature descriptors/signatures. the database/query side of things is always the same. ignore everything that talks about "hashing". images shouldn't be "hashed". they need to be *perceived*.