# importing python modules - ImageChops

Tags: python, image-processing, python-2.7, import, artificial-intelligence

I'm looking for a good way to analyze image similarity, using python.
I'm NOT looking for a way to establish whether two images are identical. I'm just looking for a way to establish the similarity between two images (e.g., if two images are very similar they could be given a "grade" of 9/10; if they are completely unalike, they'll be given a very low index, such as 2/10).
From some reading that I've done, the module ImageChops has been suggested - however, I haven't been able to find a way to download it. 
If anyone knows how to download it, or has a suggestion for other effective solutions, I'd greatly appreciate their advice!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[ImageChops is a module from PIL(Pillow)](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/blob/master/PIL/ImageChops.py). To use the ImageChops function you need to `pip install Pillow` OR `easy_install Pillow` OR [download the src](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow) & extract the src then from CMD CD to the extracted folder & run `python setup.py install`.

To use the ImageChops you can do this `from PIL import ImageChops`
you can read the [document section](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/PIL.html)

some basic usage example http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagechops.htm

To check the difference between 2 images:

```
import Image
from PIL import ImageChops

im1 = Image.open("splash.png")
im2 = Image.open("splash2.png")

diff = ImageChops.difference(im2, im1)
```

there's a [compare images script](https://gist.github.com/astanin/626356), but its not a PIL; its on [scipy module](https://github.com/scipy/scipy)
You may also check [this script here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577630-comparing-two-images/)

Comment: How Do I save the difference Image?

Comment: In my code, I had to use: `from PIL import Image` instead of  directly using `import Image`

Answer (score 3):

ImageChops is an module belong to Python Image Library(PIL). Just note that there is no image similarity algorithm (except pixel-wise) built-in in ImageChops, instead, it is a tool you used to write your own algorithm. There is a greate article here:
[How can I quantify difference between two images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189943/how-can-i-quantify-difference-between-two-images)

> The ImageChops module contains a number of arithmetical image operations, called channel operations (“chops”). These can be used for various purposes, including special effects, image compositions, algorithmic painting, and more.
>   http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagechops.htm

you can download the Python Image Library here.
http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

There are precompiled package for windows user too.
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/