# Detecting a physical ink signature on a form

Tags: python, image, ocr, document, signature

How would I detect whether a person has physically signed a paper document (at certain locations on the document_, if the document were later scanned?

My first though would be that I would scan the signed document and then compare the differences with the original ([How can I quantify difference between two images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189943/how-can-i-quantify-difference-between-two-images)), but I'm wondering if there is a better way, as I foresee issues if the document is not scanned exactly the same way each time.

Comment: I would start by getting OpenCV ... and experimenting

Comment: Maybe something like http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html