# Put back pieces of image into original image

Tags: image, image-processing

I'm looking for an algorithm to reassemble cut pieces from an image back into the correct location in the original image. For context, this is part of a solution to automatically solve a captcha. For example:

[image: Example of captcha]

I have looked at the opencv sticher class, but that appears to only work for creating "panorama images", where the edges of the images are supposed to be stuck together. The solution would probably involve some kind of shape detection to see where the pieces would go followed by a check to see if the piece "fits" into the context.

Comment: It reminds me a rigid body docking problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is simple. This algorithm replicates the way that humans would solve the problem. Here are the steps:

1. Identify the key
2. Mask out a keyhole
3. Guess what should fit in the keyhole (using inpaint)
4. Compare the key+keyhole to the inpaint image

The best fit will occur where the difference between the inpaint guess and the key+keyhole image are the lowest. This .gif explains
[image: fitting a key to a keyhole]

This is the code that I used:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
img = cv2.imread('/home/stephen/Desktop/capcha.png')
# Get key and mask of key
key = img[567:700, 145:234]
lower, upper = np.array([0,0,0]),np.array([101,255,255])
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(key, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
key_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
key = cv2.bitwise_and(key, key, mask = key_mask)
kernel = np.ones((20,20), np.uint8)
# Create a dilated mask so the key will surely fill keyhole
dilated_key_mask = key_mask.copy()
cv2.morphologyEx(dilated_key_mask, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189943/how-can-i-quantify-difference-between-two-images
from scipy.misc import imread
from scipy.linalg import norm
from scipy import sum, average

def compare_images(img1, img2):
    # normalize to compensate for exposure difference, this may be unnecessary
    # consider disabling it
    img1 = normalize(img1)
    img2 = normalize(img2)
    # calculate the difference and its norms
    diff = img1 - img2  # elementwise for scipy arrays
    m_norm = sum(abs(diff))  # Manhattan norm
    z_norm = norm(diff.ravel(), 0)  # Zero norm
    return (m_norm, z_norm)

def to_grayscale(arr):
    "If arr is a color image (3D array), convert it to grayscale (2D array)."
    if len(arr.shape) == 3:
        return average(arr, -1)  # average over the last axis (color channels)
    else:
        return arr

def normalize(arr):
    rng = arr.max()-arr.min()
    amin = arr.min()
    return (arr-amin)*255/rng

# Scan through the image
h, w, _ = img.shape
dh, dw, _ = key.shape
close_diff = h*w

graph = np.zeros((300,600,3), np.uint8)
for row in range(h-dh):
    for col in range(w-dw):
        # Create a mask of the image with the key missing
        img_temp = img.copy()
        img_mask = np.zeros((h,w), np.uint8)
        img_mask[row:row+dh, col:col+dw] = dilated_key_mask
        img_temp = cv2.bitwise_and(img_temp, img_temp, mask = 255-img_mask)
        # Inpaint to guess what should be there
        inpaint = cv2.inpaint(img_temp,img_mask,3,cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
        # Mask the key of the image 
        actual = img_temp.copy()
        actual[row:row+dh, col:col+dw] += key

        # Compare the images
        img1 = to_grayscale(inpaint)
        img2 = to_grayscale(actual)
        _, difference = compare_images(img1, img2)

        cv2.imshow('inpaint', inpaint)
        cv2.imshow('actual', actual)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

        if difference < close_diff:
            cv2.waitKey()
            close_diff = difference
            best_fit = row, col

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```