# Image saved in google Colabs Notebook is not identical to the image saved in local machine

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory, python-3.7

I have created a figure using matplotlib and saved it using savefig function.
following is the code i used,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 2, 4, 6]
y = [1, 3, 4, 8]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.box(False)
plt.savefig('plot.png')
plt.show()
```

When i run the following code in **google colabs** it generates an image with the size of **432 x 288**
When i run the same code in my **local machine** it will generates an image with the size of **640 x 480**

so i tried to resize the image which i generated in **local machine** by adding the following changes

```
plt.figure(figsize=(4.32, 2.88))
```

Using the below code to verify that both images are exactly the same, but they **are not identical**.

```
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageChops
im1 = PIL.Image.open(colab_image.png') 
im2 = PIL.Image.open(local_image.png')
if list(im1.getdata()) == list(im2.getdata()): 
    print("Identical");
else:
    print("Different");
```

Both **colab** and **my local machine** environment has -> python 3.7.0 64bit, matplotlib == 3.2.2

Please please help me to figure this issue.Because, I have no idea why this is happening. Your hep will be highly appreciated.

Here is the [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dXyuuJ6JPufTk6zRJuSgSK6UQ0PTPidl?usp=sharing)  for the **colab notebook**

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: what you get if you run following in your local? `from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
fig = plt.figure()
size = fig.get_size_inches()*fig.dpi # size in pixels
print(size)` , graph looks okay there, for size may set at os level. for me mac gave `[432. 288.]
<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>`

Comment: Hi @simpleApp ,Thanks for the quick response. I am working on windows 10 OS, After run the code you have mentioned in my local machine I've got  [640. 480.]. In colabs i've got [432. 288.] .

Comment: @simpleApp graph plotted okay but the issue is in the resolution of the image. The resolution of the image that generates in the colabs and my local machine are different. If i reshape the local machine generated image from 640 x 480 to the 432 x 288 using the code i mentioned in my question, colab image and the reshaped images are looks same but not identical. i want to create the exact identical image in my local machine that i created in the colabs.

Comment: so it is os playing a role here, what you can try is to have these two lines of code `from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
figure(figsize=(20, 20), dpi=10)` set the size and dpi, before 'plt.plot(x,y)'

Comment: @simpleApp I add the code line. Now both local machine and colab generates images 200 x 200 .  I compared them still they are not identical. Plus the size of the colab image is 2.33KB, and the size of the local machine image is 2.56KB.

Comment: I think, it needs more research and it mainly on, efficiently determine the difference between two images. this is a good resource on it [diff on two images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189943/how-can-i-quantify-difference-between-two-images)

Comment: You've already checked the following method in your matplotlib configuration. `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'];plt.rcParams['figure.dpi']`

Comment: @simpleApp , Since there is a role playing by the OS, will i able to solve this issue by using the **docker-colab-local**. which i found [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/sorokine/docker-colab-local).

Comment: @r-beginners, Thanks for reply my question. It made no change to the saved figure. It saved both the file in the default size. image generated in colabs = 432 x 288, image generated in Windows 10 = 640 x 480.

Comment: I thought that the cause of the different image sizes might be in the preferences, so I meant that you should try running the code described in the previous comment in your environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there might be an Operating System compatibility issue. Please check the code with windows and Linux/Mac environments separately.

Comment: I run the code in mac and Linux environment. However, both the times i got same 640 x 480 image.I was surprised that @simpleApp was able to generate a 432x288 size image in his mac environment but i didn't :|