# Will FFT help me in matching two images?

Tags: python, photolibrary

I wanted to create a photomosaic in python using the PIL library.

Will FFT help me in finding the best match for a picture from the given set of pictures?

I have tried with rgb colour space but the ouput seems to be ok.
I would need robust performance so thought of using fft.

Kindly provide some other valuable suggestions too.

Answer (score 2):

An implementation to spark ideas might be useful. [link](https://github.com/doda/similus)

Otherwise google "image similarity measures". The top link is going to be this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25977/how-can-i-measure-the-similarity-between-two-images) which again might provide the needed direction your looking for.