# Quick dupes search in lots of pictures

Tags: php, linux

In my grabber script I need to check every new grabbed picture for duplicates. I use php on linux server.
Does anybody know fast way to make that check. I have about 200k-300k pictures and dupes check takes a lot of time.
Easiest MD5 check is already implemented. But I need to find dupes when pictures size not match.
Thanks.

Comment: "When picture's size do not match" - how would you classify two images to be duplicates then?

Comment: Its not a dupe if the images are different in some way.

Comment: Try [Libpuzzle](http://www.pureftpd.org/project/libpuzzle/php) ... except you want a pure GD solution

Comment: http://www.imgseek.net/isk-daemon has an php api that can find a similarity percentage. I think that can help you. Or look at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25977/how-can-i-measure-the-similarity-between-two-images its provide you with the right information to check it yourself