# Google Plus default image

Tags: android, image, google-plus

Is there a way to identify [Google Plus default image](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-kOsv1Vmk57I/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAMc/SvhhDYUHktE/s120-c/photo.jpg) only by url?

If not, there is efficient way to identify it after decoding the url as bitmap?

Thanks!

Comment: You might also want to star this [issue requesting a profile object describe](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=528) if the image is default or not.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out this answer as possible solution for comparing the image content: [How can I measure the similarity between two images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25977/how-can-i-measure-the-similarity-between-two-images)