# How to match two images whether there patterens are same or not?

Tags: java, matlab, wolfram-mathematica

I want to know about that for example i have two images and wants to compare whether they are same or not i searched about it but didn't get any satisfying result also which tool or  platform is better for it MATLAB, MATHEMATICA, JAVA etc and their integration with you website.

Thanks in advance

Comment: define "the same": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25977/how-can-i-measure-the-similarity-between-two-images

Comment: Simple way would be to get the pixels of the both images, and compare their color. If all pixels have the same color, they are the same image. Note that if the images have a different amount of total pixels in them, they cannot be he same image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proposed Steps:

1. Load images
2. Extract features (color, edges locations, corner points, gabor jets)
3. Define similarity measure
4. Compute similarity score between features

This is just a quick tip to get start with some literature...
Regarding the platform I would suggest to download the library opencv in c++

http://opencv.org/

good luck