# Comparing two textures in openGL

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I'm new to OpenGL and I'm looking forward to compare two textures to understand how much they are similar to each other. I know how to to this with two bitmap images but I really need to use a method to compare two textures.

Question is: Is there any way to compare two textures as we compare two images? Like comparing two images pixel by pixel?

Comment: What is your expected end result?

Comment: "as we compare two images" As *who* compares two images? I don't know of a lot of languages that provide image comparison functions. And libraries that do provide such functions provide *many* ways to do so, with very different ideas of what it means to compare them. So it's not at all clear what it is you're asking for.

Comment: @Vertexwahn to tell me the similarity in percent value or in any other way! I just need to know is there any way? if there is, then how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25977/how-can-i-measure-the-similarity-between-two-images

Comment: Which version of OpenGL do you use? GL4.x? 3.2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually what you seem to be asking for is not possible or at least not as easy as it would seem to accomplish on the GPU. The problem is GPU is designed to accomplish as many small tasks as possible in the shortest amount of time. Iterating through an array of data such as pixels is not included so getting something like an integer or a floating value might be a bit hard.

There is one very interesting procedure you may try but I can not say the result will be appropriate for you:

You may first create a new texture that is a difference between the two input textures and then keep downsampling the result till 1x1 pixel texture and get the value of that pixel to see how different it is.

To achieve this it would be best to use a fixed size of the target buffer which is POT (power of two) for instance 256x256. If you didn't use a fixed size then the result could vary a lot depending on the image sizes.

So in first pass you would redraw the two textures to the 3rd one (using FBO - frame buffer object). The shader you would use is simply:

```
vec4 a = texture2D(iChannel0,uv);
vec4 b = texture2D(iChannel1,uv);
fragColor = abs(a-b);
```

So now you have a texture which represents the difference between the two images per pixel, per color component. If the two images will be the same, the result will be a totally black picture.

Now you will need to create a new FBO which is scaled by half in every dimension which comes to 128x128 in this example. To draw to this buffer you would need to use `GL_NEAREST` as a texture parameter so no interpolations on the texel fetching is done. Then for each new pixel sum the 4 nearest pixels of the source image:

```
vec4 originalTextCoord = varyingTextCoord;
vec4 textCoordRight = vec2(varyingTextCoord.x+1.0/256, varyingTextCoord.y);
vec4 textCoordBottom = vec2(varyingTextCoord.x, varyingTextCoord.y+1.0/256);
vec4 textCoordBottomRight = vec2(varyingTextCoord.x+1.0/256, varyingTextCoord.y+1.0/256);

fragColor = texture2D(iChannel0, originalTextCoord) + 
texture2D(iChannel0, textCoordRight) + 
texture2D(iChannel0, textCoordBottom) + 
texture2D(iChannel0, textCoordBottomRight);
```

The 256 value is from the source texture so that should come as a uniform so you may reuse the same shader.

After this is drawn you need to drop down to 64, 32, 16... Then read the pixel back to the CPU and see the result.

Now unfortunately this procedure may produce very unwanted results. Since the colors are simply summed together this will produce an overflow for all the images which are not similar enough (results in a white pixel or rather `(1,1,1,0)` for non-transparent). This may be overcome first by using a scale on the first shader pass, to divide the output by a large enough value. Still this might not be enough and an average might need to be done in the second shader (multiply all the `texture2D` calls by `.25`).

In the end the result might still be a bit strange. You get 4 color components on the CPU which represent the sum or the average of an image differential. I guess you could sum them up and choose what you consider for the images to be much alike or not. But if you want to have a more sense in the result you are getting you might want to treat the whole pixel as a single 32-bit floating value (these are a bit tricky but you may find answers around the SO). This way you may compute the values without the overflows and get quite exact results from the algorithms. This means you would write the floating value as if it is a color which starts with the first shader output and continues for every other draw call (get texel, convert it to float, sum it, convert it back to vec4 and assign as output), `GL_NEAREST` is essential here.

If not then you may optimize the procedure and use `GL_LINEAR` instead of `GL_NEAREST` and simply keep redrawing the differential texture till it gets to a single pixel size (no need for 4 coordinates). This should produce a nice pixel which represents an average of all the pixels in the differential textures. So this is the average difference between pixels in the two images. Also this procedure should be quite fast.

Then if you want to do a bit smarter algorithm you may do some wonders on creating the differential texture. Simply subtracting the colors may not be the best approach. It would make more sense to blur one of the images and then comparing it to the other image. This will lose precision for those very similar images but for everything else it will give you a much better result. For instance you could say you are interested only if the pixel is 30% different then the weight of the other image (the blurred one) so you would discard and scale the 30% for every component such as `result.r = clamp(abs(a.r-b.r)-30.0/100.0, .0, 1.0)/((100.0-30.0)/100.0);`

Comment: Another option that might be worth trying is to call `glGenerateMipmap()` on the difference texture, and read back the value of the 1x1 level from the resulting mipmap chain.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind both textures to a shader and visit each pixel by drawing a quad or something like this.

```
// Equal pixels are marked green. Different pixels are shown in red color.
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;

    vec4 a = texture2D(iChannel0,uv);
    vec4 b = texture2D(iChannel1,uv);

    if(a != b)
        fragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1);
    else
        fragColor = vec4(0,1,0,1);
}
```

You can test the shader on [Shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4ddGDX).

Or you can also bind both textures to a compute shader and visit every pixel by iteration.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to test it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare vectors. You have to use

```
if( any(notEqual(a,b)))
```

Check the GLSL language spec