# Can ANOVA be used to compare two images?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, statistics, comparison, anova

Is it possible to compare two images using ANOVA? I am trying to solve a problem where there are two classes - similar image and dissimilar. I want to classify a set of test images (comparing them to a reference image) into either similar or dissimilar. Is ANOVA a good comparison tool to accomplish this task? As always, thanks in advance!

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by image similarity and how you intend to apply ANOVA to images.

Comment: @jd1338, you might write that as an answer; I think it's worth accepting to archive the question.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Did that as suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, an ANOVA is used to compare mean values of more than two groups. If exactly two groups are supposed to be compared, a t-test would be used.

However, in your case it seems like you want to compare groups of `n=1` several times. In such a case an ANOVA wouldn't be the method of choice. Moreover, all classic statistical methods require sample sizes `> 1`, which is why I doubt that your approach is very promising.

Instead, I would rather take a look at algorithms which compare images. See here for example: [How can I measure the similarity between two images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25977/how-can-i-measure-the-similarity-between-two-images)

Comment: @troymyname00 if this answer helped, please consider selecting it as an answer by clicking on the check mark. This lets community know the answer worked and the issue is closed.